# 500 internal server error due to htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am trying to use .htaccess file in my project but when i add my htaccess its giving me 500 internal server error this is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abc?$ index.php
RewriteRule ^index/2/([a-z0-9]+) index.php?folder=aboutus&file=$1
RewriteRule ^index/3/([a-z0-9]+) 
index.php?folder=blog&file=$1
RewriteRule ^index/4/([a-z0-9]+) index.php?folder=contactus&file=$1
RewriteRule ^index/5/([a-z0-9]+) index.php?folder=courses&file=$1
RewriteRule ^index/6/([a-z0-9]+) index.php?folder=gallery&file=$1
RewriteRule ^index/7/([a-z0-9]+)
index.php?folder=home&file=$1
RewriteRule ^index/8/([a-z0-9]+) index.php?folder=courses&file=$1
RewriteRule ^index/9/([a-z0-9]+) index.php?folder=login&file=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^index/3/([a-z0-9]+) 
> index.php?folder=blog&file=$1
> ```

If your file is really formatted like this, ie. splitting directives on two lines, then this will certainly result in a 500 Internal Server Error, as it is syntactically invalid.

Whenever you get a 500 Error then you need to check your server's error log for the specifics of the error. In the case of the above then you will get something like: `RewriteRule: bad argument line`.

The above should be formatted like all your other directives, on one line:

```
RewriteRule ^index/3/([a-z0-9]+) index.php?folder=blog&file=$1
```

---

*Aside:* Since you are rewriting a URL that simply omits the file extension (ie. `.php`) that would otherwise directly map to a filesystem file then you should make sure that `MultiViews` is disabled, otherwise you can get unexpected conflicts. In other words, add the following directive to the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```